# Is it possible to print unique data on different pages in Power BI Report Builder?

Tags: powerbi, reportbuilder, powerbi-paginated-reports

I am very new to Power BI Report Builder. So far I've made a paginated report that allows the user to select a restaurant and then an employee to see how much money they've handled.

But when it comes to printing I need the option to have the first page be the total earnings of the chosen restaurant and then subsequent pages for each employee.

Is this possible?

So far with my limited knowledge I can only create parameters to display a single page with summarised data, when what I need is Page 1: All money for restaurant 1, Page 2: employee 1's intake, Page 3: employee 2's intake, etc.